# How do I move the UITabBar Item Badge so that it overlaps the top right of the bell/alerts icon in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to move the UITabBar Item badge from right to left and I'm using xamarin.ios. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CoreAnimation` transform identity matrix on the `_UIBadgeView` `UIView` class:

```
mainTabBar.Items.Each((UITabBarItem item, int index) =>
{
    item.BadgeValue = "Normal";
    foreach (var badgeView in mainTabBar.Subviews[index].Subviews)
    {
        if (index > 0)
            if (badgeView.Class.Name.Contains("_UIBadgeView"))
            {
                badgeView.Layer.Transform = new CATransform3D();
                badgeView.Layer.Transform = CATransform3D.MakeTranslation(-100, -20, 1);
                item.BadgeValue = "Custom";
                item.BadgeColor = UIColor.Green;
                item.SetBadgeTextAttributes(new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.Black }, UIControlState.Normal);
                return;
            }
    }
});
```

[image]